# vtkInteractorObserver::GrabFocus method

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm new to VTK.

I was reading VTK sources and in **Rendering/vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor.cxx** I found this method:

```
void vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor::OnLeftButtonDown() 
{
  int x = this->Interactor->GetEventPosition()[0];
  int y = this->Interactor->GetEventPosition()[1];

  this->FindPokedRenderer(x, y);
  this->FindPickedActor(x, y);
  if (this->CurrentRenderer == NULL || this->InteractionProp == NULL)
    {
    return;
    }

  this->GrabFocus(this->EventCallbackCommand);
  if (this->Interactor->GetShiftKey())
    {
    this->StartPan();
    }
  else if (this->Interactor->GetControlKey())
    {
    this->StartSpin();
    }
  else
    {
    this->StartRotate();
    }
}
```

Can you explain what call
    ***this->GrabFocus(this->EventCallbackCommand);***
actually does?

In docs I found

```
void vtkInteractorObserver::GrabFocus(vtkCommand *mouseEvents, 
                                      vtkCommand *keypressEvents = NULL)
```

> These methods enable an interactor observer to exclusively grab all events invoked by its associated vtkRenderWindowInteractor. (This method is typically used by widgets to grab events once an event sequence begins.) The GrabFocus() signature takes up to two vtkCommands corresponding to mouse events and keypress events. (These two commands are separated so that the widget can listen for its activation keypress, as well as listening for DeleteEvents, without actually having to process mouse events.)

But I don't really understand what they mean. Please give me some simple examples how this method is typically used.